# Cannot change the length of String(250) to String using Alembic and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I would like to change from

`description = Column(String(250))`

to

`description = Column(String)`

When I generate migration file using below command, it's getting empty.

`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Changing the column size"`

Generated migration file:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands
```

Note:
I alreday have `compare_type=True` settings in alembic

`context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata, compare_type=True)`

It generates migration file with alter function when I change `String(250)` to `String(500)` but not for `String(250)` to `String`, Seems alembic does not support it!

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps try `String(None)` …?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GordThompson unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 10):

If Alembic is unable to detect the change from `String(250)` to `String()` then you'll have to work around it like this:

Change the column in your model to `String(251)` and run

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Modified description column"
```

to generate a revision file that contains something like

```py
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('table1', 'description',
               existing_type=sa.VARCHAR(length=250, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
               type_=sa.String(length=251),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('table1', 'description',
               existing_type=sa.String(length=251),
               type_=sa.VARCHAR(length=250, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Edit that file to change the new column type to `String()` …

```py
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('table1', 'description',
               existing_type=sa.VARCHAR(length=250, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
               type_=sa.String(),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('table1', 'description',
               existing_type=sa.String(),
               type_=sa.VARCHAR(length=250, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

… and edit your model to use `String()` as well. Then run the migration

```
alembic upgrade head
```

When I tested this with SQL Server it changed the column type from `varchar(250)` to `varchar(MAX)`.

Comment: This was what I had done on last Friday and it was working fine with Postgres, thanks for your time too!